# Upgrading from ubuntu 16 to ubuntu 18

Tags: matlab

I have matlab installed on ubuntu 16 LTS and I want to upgrade my ubuntu to 18 LTS. My question is whether the process will uninstall my matlab or  not?

Comment: If you're asking about Ubuntu Core 16 to Ubuntu 18 Core as the heading suggests, software that runs in any Ubuntu Core (*yy* format Ubuntu product) will run on any system without change, so an upgrade from Ubuntu Core 16 to Ubuntu Core 18 only changes the underlying OS and programs/applications are not touched, as *snaps* are the same for any product.  This doesn't apply to *deb* based *year.month* products but you don't mention them (all *year* products come with 10 years of supported life, LTS isn't generally used)

Answer (score 1):

Even latest MATLAB does not come in deb-packages.
It is usually installed to `/opt` or `/usr/local` or into your home folder.

So it will not be removed by upgrade in any way.